# How to export a volume mesh?

Tags: export, mesh

Let's say that I generate a volume mesh using the following command:

`Icosahedron[] // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics // TriangulateMesh`

which gives the following:
[image]

As you can see from the images this is a volume mesh.
When I export it as vtk, it just prints the boundary mesh only.
Is there a way to export the volume mesh (the actual tetrahedrons)?
I would like to visualise the mesh in ParaView.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does `Icosahedron[] // DiscretizeGraphics // TriangulateMesh` give what you need?

Comment: No. It's the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that *Mathematica* only exports surface data to VTK (i.e., Polygons) and the format that it exports in an old format and not the new XML format. The following bullet point from the *Background & Context* section of the [`VTK`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VTK.html) documentation describes the limitation.

> - *Stores a single 3D object as a collection of line, point, and polygon primitives and their properties.*

I looked up the structure of a VTK version 3.0 unstructured mesh format [here](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/VTKFileFormats/#legacy-file-examples).

Here is simple example of an export of a single unstructured quad element:

`# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
vtk output by Tim Laska
ASCII
DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID
POINTS 4 double
0 0 0
1 0 0
0 1 0
1.1 1.1 0
CELLS 1 5
4 0 1 3 2
CELL_TYPES 1
10`

It is relatively straightforward to output tetrahedra using *Mathematica's* [`StringTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html) functionality as shown in the following workflow that will write a tet mesh in the `NotebookDirectory`  that I wrapped in a module.

```
m = Icosahedron[] // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics // TriangulateMesh;
mcrd = MeshCoordinates[m];
minc = Delete[0] /@ MeshCells[m, 3];
(* Set Directory To Notebook *)
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
vtk[c_, i_, fn_ : "test.vtk"] := Module[
  {vtkTemplate, nPoints, nInc, nTotal,
   crdtmp, inctmp, typetmp, crd, inc, types, assoc, file
   },
  vtkTemplate = 
   StringTemplate[
    Uncompress[
     "1:eJw1ytEKgjAUxnEf5UT3YfUE4iwGYrIdgyBwU3cxtE3cDHzA3isneHX+\
nN93aCzjvyiKjvD1PRDp5U0PCp5qctoauJ7id3y+\
BLOzH2cPzQKoP5BL18tACU8pDUESTHiGUBUcWZVixTJS3xklAcsHLZCDMKXVxjsBnZ2bQQ\
US7dSJEGmW52FCTSvWg9bLYQOh18++qPFVZvtsU7+Mym35Bx3aQTM="]];
  nPoints = Length@mcrd;
  nInc = Length@minc;
  nTotal = 5*nInc;
  crdtmp = StringTemplate["`1` `2` `3`\n"];
  inctmp = StringTemplate["4 `1` `2` `3` `4`\n"];
  typetmp = StringTemplate["`1`\n"];
  crd = StringJoin[crdtmp @@@ c];
  inc = StringJoin[inctmp @@@ (i - 1)];
  types = StringJoin[typetmp /@ ConstantArray[10, nInc]];
  assoc = <|"nPoints" -> nPoints, "nInc" -> nInc,
    "crd" -> crd, "inc" -> inc, "nTotal" -> nTotal,
    "types" -> types|>;
  (* Write stream *)
  file = OpenWrite[fn];
  WriteString[file, vtkTemplate[assoc]];
  Close[file];
  vtkTemplate[assoc]
  ]
vtk[mcrd, minc, "myTest.vtk"];
```

Now, we can view a "crinkly" clip plane in Paraview, which shows that we have exported the tetrahedra and not just the surface mesh.

[image: tetrahedral mesh]

Comment: You are the boss. Thank you.